# Displaying the same button name in JSP after ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a jsp page where a corresponding to every data row, there is a button, on click of which there is some activity performed. Am using ajax and showing the response in a separate window. The user can click on multiple buttons and perform multiple activities. The issue for me is that i want to show that "Activity in progress" when the activity is started and disable that particular button. When the response is received, then enable the button and also rename the button same as the previous name. But i have not able to do as i am able to enable one button only and rename it through the response button when am running multiple activities. for one activity , the whole thing works fine. I am using simple java script,ajax and jsp for my work. Can some one suggest the way to do that so that appropriate action is performed after the response is received.All the buttons are having a unique ID.

Comment: add jsp page, and what code you tried so far.

Comment: var ele=""; function exeMntrScript(script,element,app,env,region) { ele=element; var mon_id=element.getAttribute('id'); element.value='Checking Server Status ..'; element.disabled='disabled'; makeHttpRequest(contextPath+"/jsp/consoleInfo/wlsAppsStatusCheck.jsp?script="‌​+script+"&mon_id="+mon_id+"&app="+app+"&env="+env+"&region="+region,appResponse,f‌​alse); } function appResponse(appres) { ele.value="Check Server Status"; ele.disabled=''; var myWindow = window.open(); myWindow.document.write( appres ); myWindow.focus(); }

Comment: I have been able to find my solution my making below changes to the response function.
function appResponse(appres)
 { 
  var result = $(appres).filter('#mon_id');
  
  var req_id=result.val();
  document.getElementById(req_id).value='Check Server Status';
  document.getElementById(req_id).disabled='';
  
  var myWindow = window.open();
     myWindow.document.write( appres );
     myWindow.focus();
  
 }